# How to display a custom dialog using PyQt and QtDesigner to design the custom dialog?

Tags: pyqt

I have designed 2 widgets - one is the main application widget and a custom widget which would allow me to set the preferences in my main application. They are named - main and child.

Now, I can't get the child widget to show when I click the button in the main application.
Tried to learn from the Rapid GUI programming using Python and Qt book, but the example given there is for a hand coded form and not designed using QtDesigner. I am getting confused. Kindly help.

My code so far is this-

```
import serial, sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from main import Ui_Form                      # main.py and child.py are the ui 
from child import Ui_Form as Child_Form       # files generated using pyuic4

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.ui.btnLaunch, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.show)
    def show(self):
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.ui = Child_Form()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Main()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, nothing happens when I try to launch this program.

Comment: You are overriding the show method of your QMainWindow.  Try naming that method something else, or move that code into your init function.

Comment: here is the official documents for this: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html

Comment: @MikeRamirez link broken. Here's one that works: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code:

```
self.connect(self.ui.btnLaunch, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.show)
def show(self):
    dialog = QDialog()
    dialog.ui = Child_Form()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(self)
```

try with this, it should work:

```
self.connect(self.ui.btnLaunch, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.showDialog)
def showDialog(self):
    dialog = QDialog()
    dialog.ui = Child_Form()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(self)
    dialog.show()
```